# db2 doesn't allow to use function in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have the following error

```
   An unexpected token "table" was found following "elect .."
```

That is produced after the code below. 
If I call the function it works fine

```
   --example
   select * from foo('2013-02-20')
```

but when I plug it into a stored proceddure it deosnt' work. 
Is it allowed to call in a function like the one I did below?

```
   create function foo( my_date date ) returns table(data integer) 
   language sql READS SQL DATA  return select id,sum(value) from table where date=my_date group by id; 

   create procedure list_open_positions(my_date date) 
   LANGUAGE SQL begin select * from table(foo(my_date)); end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stored procedures can't contain a bare select statement, as they don't output the results of queries directly.

The table function should work fine in a select statement that is part of an expression.  For example:

```
create procedure bar(my_date date)
language sql
begin
    insert into some_table
         select * from table(foo(my_date));
end
```

*This answer is not 100% definitive without knowing the version and platform of DB2 you are using.  There are major differences between versions in what is allowed in functions/procedures.  An example such as above works fine in 9.7 for LUW.*

Comment: HI DAn! Thanks! Are you saying that in principle I cannot create a stored procedure JUST to print out the result of that function? I want to do that for users that don't want to deal with SQL at all. My goal is creating a stored procedure that wraps that call and prints the results on screen instead of running 'db2 "select * from table(foo(my_date))'. I thought it was a silly task!!

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile, that is correct, you can't do that.  If you have users that don't want to deal with SQL at all, you could create an SQL file, then they could just run the file and see the result.  Or, for a little more work, you could create a small script (in almost any programming language) that runs a query and shows the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found all people complaining about this. I will do what you suggest.